# Do CSS classes slow websites down?

Tags: css, drupal

I've noticed in Materialize CSS there are a lot of classes in their template (making the CSS document up to 8000 lines long). I've also heard Drupal can be similar, adding a lot of unneccacary classes to the code.

Would the excess of classes in the CSS document cause a noticable delay in how long it takes for a page to load? 
Wouldn't the computer have to go on a wild goose chase for each class?

(I've tried searching for answers to this question, but they were usually specific to one situation)